# Are $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}} - 1, (1+p)^{p^{n-2}} - 1$ divisible by $p^n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Is it true that $p^n$ divides $(1+p)^{p^{n-1}}-1$ if $p$ is an odd prime ? Furthermore, does $p^n$ divide $(1+p)^{p^{n-2}}-1$?

I tried to show the following, but made no progress:

$$ p^n \text{ divides } \binom{p^{n-1}}{k}p^k \text{ for each } k=1,\,2,\,\cdots,\,p^{n-1}$$

How to show this?

Comment: That means you have an answer to the first question, right? And do you ever use that $p$ is an *odd* prime? And I think it can lead to answer to the second question—$p^n$ *doesn't* divide the term $\binom{p^{n-2}}{1}p$, but what about the other terms?

Comment: @Jackson Thanks for the comment. I edited my question to make my point clear.

Answer (score 2):

LTE lemma is a good choice to prove it

If $p＝2$,then $p\mid 0$.
Let $p>2$ and  $p\mid (p+1)-1$, then we have
$$v_p((1+p)^{p^{n-1}}-1)＝v_p((1+p)-1)+v_p(p^{n-1})＝n$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the LTE lemma. Can you state it in your answer?

Comment: Actually, rereading OP's edits, I think a proof sketch of LTE lemma would be extremely useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logarithm map (at least for $p > 2$ and for $p=2$, it works if you replace $(1+2)^{2^n}$ with $(1+4)^{2^n}$). The idea is the following:

We can define a group homomorphism $\log_p: (1 + p\mathbb Z_p)^\times \to \mathbb pZ_p$ by the usual infinite series:
$$\log_p(1+x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \dots$$
It's not hard to check that this always converges and takes multiplication to addition. Moreover, it has an inverse $\exp_p$ but this only converges for $p \geq 3$ or on $4\mathbb Z_2$ for $p = 2$.

Anyway, once you have the idea to consider these maps, it's a routine calculation. $\log_p(1+p) = p\times \text{unit}$ so $\log_p(1+p)^{p^n} = p^{n+1}\times\text{unit} $ so taking exponentials, we see that $(1+p)^{p^n} - 1$ is exactly divisible by $p^{n+1}$.